# What does =] mean in C#?

Tags: c#, semantics

I have come across some syntax I've never seen before; can someone explain the syntax of line 2 in the following code, specifically the `=]` bits?

```
//decide what to do with the response we get back from the bridge
client.UploadStringCompleted += (o, args) =] Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =]
{
    try
    {
        ResponseTextBox.Text = args.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResponseTextBox.Text = ex.Message;
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, web searches don't seem to parse `=]`, which is frustrating my attempts to find an explanation!

Comment: It's not `]` but just `>`

Comment: Where does this example comes from?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx RTM

Comment: arr ... please someone close based on offtopic - typo ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: just have. Sadly I can't do it solo. :)

Comment: @Chris Sadly I've retracted my close vote after the answer got fixed ... Now it is reverted ... :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cursory search for the text in the comment in the given code listing leads to [this Channel 9 article](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Philips-Hue-Lighting-Controller). There are two occurrences of this statement, one of which presents the same lambda expressions with the correct syntax `=>`:

```
//decide what to do with the response we get back from the bridge
client.UploadStringCompleted += (o, args) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    try
    {
        ResponseTextBox.Text = args.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResponseTextBox.Text = ex.Message;
    }

});
```

It becomes abundantly clear, therefore, that what you're looking at is a typo on part of the author of said article.

AFAIK, there is no legal C# construct that consists of the characters `=]`, in that order, even accounting for whitespace. In your particular example it's most definitely a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you very much. No wonder I was confused!

Comment: @BoltClock: Should this not be closed as offtopic/typo then? I ask because you seem to be a mod and would have expected you to do that rather than put in an answer...

Comment: @Chris: I was wondering the same thing tbh. The difference here is that the typo comes from an external source outside of the author's control; it is not a mistake made by the author in composing their question.

Comment: @BoltClock: so is the current close reason incorrect?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: IMO, yes. I generally only apply this close reason to questions stemming from a mistake made by the asker (and even then, only if it's unlikely to help future readers, as stated in the description). But that's just my opinion and my own interpretation of the close reason.

Comment: @Grant Winney: The latter.

Comment: Also, feel free to take this to meta; I'd like to see what the community at large thinks of this.

Comment: Despite the discussion this has caused I've marked the above as an accepted answer on the off chance this helps someone else. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm not fussed enough to take this to Meta (especially given it is closed now so I don't think any more needs to be done). My personal view on the off topic/typo is that if the root cause is a typo then the question is kind of meaningless. So in this case asking "what does =] mean in c#" is a meaningless question since that syntax doesn't exist in c#. And there are plenty of questions probably asking what does => mean already so once the typo is recognised I don't feel it adds much. That having been said I am certainly happy with it having an accepted answer while it is here. :)

Comment: @Chris: Agreed - in retrospect, it would have been trivial to find out if this really was legal syntax simply by trying to run it.